# Identify trends from thousands of time series plots

Tags: time-series, forecasting, generalized-additive-model, intermittent-time-series

Not sure if this is the right place to post this. I have like 100s of thousands of time series data and their respective graphs. I want to be able to classify the general trend for all of these curves whether they are trending downwards or upwards or constant throughout. Not sure how to go about it. Maybe apply time series models but most data may not even meet stationarity conditions. Or maybe use GAMs? I don't know. I would really appreciate if someone can shed some light on this. I have attached 30 random sample plots. (Each pic has 15 random sample plots). Thanks[image: sample plots 1][image: sample plots 2]

Comment: It does not sound like statistics it sounds a judgement/classification you make of a specific curve. What are you going to do with curves that are not monotonic - how will these be classified? I have never seen times series used for this purpose.

Comment: @user54285 Honestly, I am not really concerned about non-monotonic curves. The main objective is to be able to identify the samples that may eventually drop close to zero. Anything else is just a bonus.

Comment: Well you have to decide what eventually means, how many months for example. You can identify which curves will be at certain values within certain time frames. The forecast module in R will allow you to predict future values for arima and will select the model fairly quickly with auto.arima. But Arima assumes linearity so if it is monotonic or not will matter. Also you have to assume no structural breaks. I would imagine you can run thousands in a week or so. You might look at the literature on the M contests as well.

Comment: If zero is the smallest allowed value are the series integer or continuous responses?

Comment: @GavinSimpson Yeah, the target variable is a discrete variable and zero is the smallest value possible.

Comment: @user54285 Thanks. I would say three months.  I am not really familiar with time series models tbh although I know some basics. So far, I have mostly worked with supervised learning. Could you please point me to a good resource for ARIMA?

Comment: I am cautious recommending anything because I am not a statistician or an expert in any way in ARIMA. I gave up in the classical approach using PACF and ACF in recent years to use search tools (auto.arima specifically) which I think others have as well given the problems with the classical way of doing ARIMA particularly with mixed models.